# IllegalArgumentException: Firebase Storage URLs must point to an object in your Storage Bucket when trying to link a cloudinary URL to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Cloudiary service in order to decrease the size of an uploaded video. I am getting back a URL of a picture (which I assume is the first frame of the video) back as a response. When trying to load the video from firebase I am for some reason getting a URL and not a URI. here is my method -

```
 private void loadVideoUri(String storageUri) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(storageUri)) {
            return;
        }

        // load firebase storage
        Task<Uri> downloadUrlTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(storageUri).getDownloadUrl(); // -> crash happends here
        if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
            downloadUrlTask.addOnCompleteListener((Activity) getContext(), mOnDownloadUrlCompleted);
        } else {
            downloadUrlTask.addOnCompleteListener(mOnDownloadUrlCompleted);
        }

    }
```

here is the full error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Firebase Storage URLs must point to an object in your Storage Bucket. Please obtain a URL using the Firebase Console or getDownloadUrl().
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.normalize(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:134)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:281)
        at com.onemdtalent.app.ui.views.mdview.FirebasePlayerView.loadVideoUri(FirebasePlayerView.java:156)
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing a URL that doesn't point directly to a file. Are you maybe pointing to the bucket instead of the file? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#create_a_reference

Comment: what is the value of storageUri

Comment: the value is a valid URL